# Android Calendar Provider Alarm is set to false

Tags: java, android, calendar

i'm making an application that creates events and add them to The System calendar programmatically , i'm having a problem that my code set's the Alarm (or Reminder) off 
here is my method

```
public void setEventinCalendar(String name,String description,int year,int month,int day)
{
    long startMillis = 0; 
    long endMillis = 0;     
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(year,month,day);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(year,month,day);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, name+"'s Event");
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1); 
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION,description);
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
    String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,timeZone);
    Uri baseUri= Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    getContentResolver().insert(baseUri,values);
}
```

and is it possible to set the time that the alarm or reminder will show ?? 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution ,, The Calendar Reminder can't Remind you in specific time 
and to add reminder to your Calender use this method

```
public void setEventinCalendar(String name,String description,int year,int month,int day,int hour,int minute)
{
    long startMillis = 0; 
    long endMillis = 0;     
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(year,month,(day),hour,minute);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(year,month,(day),hour,minute);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, name+"'s Event");
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1); 
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION,description);
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
    values.put(Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS,Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
    values.put(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_FREE);
    String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,timeZone);
    Uri uri=getContentResolver().insert(Events.CONTENT_URI,values);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Reminders.MINUTES, TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(3, TimeUnit.HOURS));
    values.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
    values.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
    uri = getContentResolver().insert(Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event has been Added to Your Calendar ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```